# change one of reccuring event from workflow

Tags: workflow, events

We need create a workflow which change for example category column(work-->done) When We create in Sharepoint Designer workflow with action update list item, this action change all series, however in calendar is option change only 1 day from series.
how to create a workflow?
Please help.